# IEEE Referencing -- access dates for online references

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, ieeetran

This is my bibliography file:

```
@book{bhp-billit-background,
    title       = "BHP Billiton -- Olympic Dam Australia",
    booktitle   = "Water Management in Mining - A Selection of Case Studies",
    year        = "2012",
    url         = "https://app.knovel.com/hotlink/khtml/id:kt010RLMZ3/water-management-in-mining/bhp-billit-background",
    isbn        = "978-0-9559983-7-9",
    publisher   = "International Council on Mining and Metals (ICMM)",
    urldate     = {2021-08-15}
}

@article{mesa_olympic_dam_geology,
    title       = {{Geology of the Olympic Dam Cu–U–Au–Ag–REE deposit}},
    author      = "Lachlan J. Reynolds",
    journal     = "MESA Journal",
    volume      = "23",
    pages       = "4--11",
    month       = "Oct.",
    year        = "2001"
}

@article{eb_bhp, 
    title       = {{BHP Billiton}}, 
    url         = {https://www.britannica.com/topic/BHP-Billiton}, 
    journal     = {Encyclopaedia Britannica}, 
    publisher   = {Encyclopaedia Britannica, Inc.}, 
    date        = {2006-05-11},
    urldate     = {2021-08-15}
}

@online{bhp_history, 
    title       = {Our History}, 
    url         = {https://www.bhp.com/our-approach/our-history/}, 
    website     = {{BHP website}}, 
    urldate     = {2021-08-15}
}
```

However, when I run my Latex script, the access dates aren't getting printed onto the PDF file:

[image: References]

Does anyone know what I can do about this? Thanks.

EDIT: This script would be my minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[twoside,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in, right=0.5in]{geometry} % Defines margins

\begin{document}

\cite{eb_bhp}, \cite{bhp_history}, \cite{bhp-billit-background}, \cite{mesa_olympic_dam_geology}. 

\bibliographystyle{IEEETRAN}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

I used Texmaker and I ran it it with BibTeX before running it twice with the default "Quick Build" setting, and the PDF would basically be the same bibliography as the one shown above but without the "7".

Comment: Please tell us what your bibliography setup looks like. (I.e. show us a small example document that reproduces the output from the screenshot with as little excess code as possible: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Comment: Currently the question is hard to answer, because there are several IEEE styles available for LaTeX: One is the `biblatex-ieee` style, which should not be used with `ieeetran`, because `ieeetran` comes with a variety of BibTeX styles. The question is tagged both `biblatex` and `ieeetran`, so we can't tell what you are doing.

Comment: FWIW I checked with `biblatex-ieee` and it displays the access date, so you are probably not using `biblatex`. **That does not mean that the solution is to switch to `biblatex`, though!** If you want to submit an article to the IEEE you should use their document class and templates, which explicitly come with their own styles and are incompatible with `biblatex`.

Comment: AFAICS `IEEEtran.bst` simply has no field for URL access date. If you need it, you can probably cook something up using the `note` field.